# autohotkey - hotkey to toggle between Minimize and Restore for current selected window

Tags: autohotkey, restore, window

I would like to create a single hotkey to toggle between Minimize and Restore for current selected window (explorer window, or program window, or any window), but I need the toggle to min and restore that exact same window. If no window is selected do nothing.

So far I have done this

```
#s::
if (!CW)
    {
    WinGetPos, winWidth, winHeight, , , A

    if ( winWidth == -8 and winHeight == -8)
        {
        WinGet, CW
        WinMinimize, CW
        }
} else
{
    WinRestore, CW
}
```

It does not work

I also tried this,

```
#s::
if (!%active_id%)
{
    WinGet, active_id, ID, A
    WinMinimize, ahk_id %active_id%
}
else
{
WinRestore, ahk_id %active_id%
}
```

it minized the window the first time the hotkey is pressed and the second time the hotkey is pressed instead of restoring the windows, it just keeps minimizing other windows and so on. please help, I need a toggle

I took this example from other post looking for a toggle,

```
#s::
WinGet MX, MinMax, A
If MX
WinRestore A
Else WinMaximize A
return
```

this toggle works but only between Maximize and Restore the same windows, I wan't to toggle between Minimize and Restore the same window, I guess I don't only need the toggle but a way to store the windows ID, so it can remember which window to restore once the windows is minized.

THanks Advanced.

Comment: when a window is minimized, doesn't it also become inactive?

Comment: I'm taking a stab in the dark, but have you ever tried Alt + Tab? Alt + Tab done quick will bounce you between two different windows(current and last window). If you Hold Alt and press Tab, then you can tab until you get to the window you want (all windows). Interesting idea otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#s::
; If no window is already selected 
; or the selected window doesn't exist anymore, 
; select the currently active window and minimize it:
IfWinNotExist, ahk_id %selected_id%
{
    If (IsWindow(WinExist("A")) || WinActive("ahk_class ArtRage 3"))
        WinGet, selected_id, ID, A
    else
    {
        MsgBox, No window selected
            return
    }
}
WinGet, WinState, MinMax, ahk_id %selected_id%
    If WinState = -1    ; the selected window is minimized  
    {
        WinRestore
        selected_id := ""       
    }
    else
        WinMinimize
return

; This checks if a window is, in fact a window,
; as opposed to the desktop or a menu, etc.
IsWindow(hwnd){
   WinGet, s, Style, ahk_id %hwnd%
   return s & 0xC00000 ? (s & 0x100 ? 0 : 1) : 0
}
```

Comment: Thanks user3419297, I'm very thankfull, I just posted another question, could you please check it out? thanks advanced http://superuser.com/questions/1147980/autohotkey-hotkey-1-do-something-key-sequence-11-do-another-thing

Comment: by the way, what does `return s & 0xC00000 ? (s & 0x100 ? 0 : 1) : 0` mean?

Comment: "0xC00000" and "0x100" are numbers representing styles of windows. See the [styles table](https://autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Styles.htm) for a partial listing of styles. The function returns 0 (false), if the variable "style" has one of these two values.

Comment: Is it not necessary to add a `return` at the end of this script????, because I have several other scripts below this, and I think they are not working because of this is above of the `IsWindow(hwnd){
   WinGet, s, Style, ahk_id %hwnd%
   return s & 0xC00000 ? (s & 0x100 ? 0 : 1) : 0
}` Thanks Advanced.

Comment: Hi user3419297 the script works fine, it recognized MSword, and Photoshop, but it doesnt recognize ArtRage `"ahk_class ArtRage 3"` when I press on an ArtRage window, it displays the msgbox saying No window selected, How can I tweak that. thanks advanced.

Comment: See the edited answer. || means ''or''.

Comment: tahnks a lot man!

Answer (score 1):

```
    #s::
    select_window:
; If no window is already selected or the selected window doesn't exist anymore, 
; select the currently active window:
IfWinNotExist, ahk_id %selected_id%
{
    If IsWindow(WinExist("A"))
        WinGet, selected_id, ID, A
    else
    {
        MsgBox, No window selected
            return
    }
}
WinGet, WinState, MinMax, ahk_id %selected_id%
    If WinState = -1    ; the window is minimized
        WinRestore ahk_id %selected_id%
    else
        WinMinimize, ahk_id %selected_id%
return

; select another window to toggle its state:
    !#s::
selected_id := ""
GoSub, select_window    ; or: GoSub, #s
return

; This checks if a window is, in fact a window,
; as opposed to the desktop or a menu, etc.
IsWindow(hwnd){
   WinGet, s, Style, ahk_id %hwnd%
   return s & 0xC00000 ? (s & 0x100 ? 0 : 1) : 0
}
```

Comment: Thanks user3419297, but is it possible to do it with only one hotkey? a toggle hotkey? I mean, in your script I use !#s to select the windows I want to minimize and restore, and I use #s to minimize and restore the windows selected by !#s, but I want to use a single toggle hotkey #s to directly minimize and restore the currently selected window. THKs

Comment: The !#s-combination is only necessary for changing the window
you want toggle. What you describe is also doable, but more complicated and costs more time and effort to you than the pressing of one more key.

Comment: sorry to bother you, I just wanted to use a single key to toggle between minimize n restore, I didn't know it was not sensible to do it, thanks anyway.

Comment: Please somebody help!

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "current selected window"? How do you select this window?

Comment: Hi user3419297 I select it by making click on it, lets say I clicked on a MS word window, then I would like to use the WinS hotkey to minimize it. then open other windows, navigate on google, and when I press again WinS I want the MSword window to restore. Then the next time I press WinS, the window that is selected (currently been used / on focus, lets say is excel) should be minimized, and the next time I hit WinS it should restore excel again. Thanks Advanced.

Comment: See my next answer.

Comment: Thanks user3419297, I'm very thankfull, I just posted another question, could you please check it out? thanks advanced http://superuser.com/questions/1147980/autohotkey-hotkey-1-do-something-key-sequence-11-do-another-thing

Comment: by the way, what does `return s & 0xC00000 ? (s & 0x100 ? 0 : 1) : 0` mean?