# Autohotkey - hotkey 1 do something, key sequence 11 do another thing

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey, hotkeys

Im pretty new in AHK, I would like Autohotkey to whenever I press the hotkey "1" in MS Word type HELLOW, but at the same time in the same app (MS Word) I want the key combination "11" (key 1 pressed two times very quickly) to type BYE, is this possible? will AHK type "1HELLOW" when I type "1", will it type "11BYE" when I type "11"? is it possible to do the same script but with F1 instead? I mean F1, and the key sequence F1F1 (F1 pressed twice very quickly)

So far I have tried this

```
~1::
;400 is the maximum allowed delay (in milliseconds) between presses.
if (A_PriorHotKey = "~1" AND A_TimeSincePriorHotkey < 400)
{
   Msgbox,Double press detected.
}
else if (A_PriorHotKey = "~1" AND A_TimeSincePriorHotkey > 400)
{
    Msgbox,Single press detected.
}

Sleep 0
KeyWait 1
return
```

But it just work the first time I press the key sequence 11 (1 pressed twice quickly) then it will always recognize only the 1 key, why???

```
~1::
if (A_PriorHotkey <> "~1" or A_TimeSincePriorHotkey > 400)
{
    ; Too much time between presses, so this isn't a double-press.
    KeyWait, 1
    return
}
MsgBox You double-pressed the 1 key.
return
```

this doesn't help to get the two hotkeys, (1 and 11) either.

Thanks Advanced.

Comment: Looking into this quickly, it seems variables are of local scope, so they die when the script ends.  This one might help, through: [special variable A_PriorKey](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#PriorKey) (or A_PriorHotKey or A_ThisHotKey, located nearby in documentation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works best by using SetTimer:

```
    ; The following hotkeys work only if MS-WORD is the active window:
#If WinActive("ahk_exe WINWORD.EXE")    ; (1)

    1::
    if 1_presses > 0
    {
        1_presses += 1
        SetTimer Key1, 300
        return
    }
    1_presses = 1
    SetTimer Key1, 300
    return

    Key1:
    SetTimer Key1, off
    if 1_presses = 2
      SendInput, BYE
    else
      SendInput, HELLOW
    1_presses = 0
    return

    F2:: MsgBox, You pressed F2 in MS-Word


    ; The following hotkeys work only if NOTEPAD is the active window:
#If WinActive("ahk_exe NOTEPAD.EXE") 

    1:: Send 2

    F2:: MsgBox, You pressed F2 in NOTEPAD


#If ; turn off context sensitivity (= end of context-sensitive hotkeys)


; The following hotkeys work only if MS-WORD or NOTEPAD is NOT the active window (because they are already defined in those programs):

1:: Send 3

F2:: MsgBox, You pressed F2 while  MS-WORD or NOTEPAD is NOT the active window


; The following hotkeys work in all windows (incl. MS-WORD and NOTEPAD because they are NOT defined in those programs)

F3:: MsgBox, You pressed F3

Esc:: ExitApp
```

https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetTimer.htm#Examples (Example #3)

(1) Like the [#IfWin](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_IfWinActive.htm) directives, [#If](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_If.htm#Parameters) creates context-sensitive hotkeys and hotstrings and is positional: it affects all hotkeys and hotstrings physically beneath it in the script.

Comment: Hi user3419297 thanks for your support, It worked like a charm even with the F1 key, I just wonder lets say I have lots of scripts that run only in MSword, (like 1pressed twice, 2pressed twice, 3 pressed twice, and other different like Ctrl Alt P) I just put `#If WinActive("ahk_exe WINWORD.EXE")    ; (1)` at the very beginning of all of them, and only put `#If ; turn off context sensitivity` at the end of all of them, right?

Comment: Answer to your first question: You only need one script for defining hotkeys or hotstrings in MSword and in any other program. I edited my answer to help you better understand, how context-sensitive hotkeys work.Please, delete your second question and add it after this comment in case my answer doesn't satisfy you.

Comment: Thanks user3419297, I got it, but what if in MSword I have script that is triggered when ` `1 ` (the key above tab and 1) is pressed in sequence, and another when just the 1 is pressed, both scripts only run in MSword, I mean, if I press the first key sequence will it trigger the second script also??? do they interfere with each other? Thanks Advanced.

Comment: btw I have also some little question http://superuser.com/questions/1148186/autohotkey-set-a-hotkey-to-toggle-disabled-enabled-a-hole-autohotkey-script Thanks agian

Comment: How do you define this sequence in the script? Add the code in your question or (better) make a new question in Super User.

Comment: Hi, thanks user 3419297 I made the new questions http://superuser.com/questions/1148238/autohotkey-1-key-sequence please could you check it? Thanks Advanced.