# Autohotkey - set a hotkey to toggle (disabled-enabled a hole autohotkey script)

Tags: autohotkey, hotkeys

Hi I used to use at the beginning of my Autohotkey script toggle between totally disable it and totally enable it
    scrolllock:: Pause

but it doesn't work anymore, and I have realize that if I set it, it will not let me set variables. e.g.

```
scrolllock:: Pause
var := 29    ; <--- this var will not be set cuz the line above
```

It will only be set if I remove the line above, I have tested it.

I have tried to change it to...

```
f12::
Pause
Suspend
return
```

but it doesn't work with the scrollock key
I guess I need to set a keystate

How can I do this, thanks Advanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will never run

```
scrolllock:: Pause

var := 29 

F1:: MsgBox, %var%
```

because you try to set a variable between hotkeys.

A variable has to be defined in the auto executable section of the script (top of the script, before the first return or hotkey)

```
; top of the script:
var := 29
    return      ; end of auto-execute section

scrolllock:: Pause

F1:: MsgBox, %var%
```

or in a hotkey

```
scrolllock:: Pause

F1:: 
var := 29
MsgBox, %var%
return
```

or in a function.

Comment: Hi user3419297 once the AHK script is running, I use the hotkey (scroll Lock) to pause it, but its hotkeys are still functional (they are still working) so if I press `space & e` I get the script to run some actions. I have noticed that the hotkeys trully get disabled only when I right click the AHK script icon on the taskbar and choose `Suspend Hotkyes` I would like suspend and renabled AHK hotkeys using the `scroll Look` key. Hot can I do taht??

Comment: Replace "scrolllock:: Pause" with "scrolllock:: Suspend".

Answer (score 0):

### AHK One-Liners

Just place `Pause` on a new line and add a `return` statement.

```lua
scrolllock:: Pause ; <-- Quick One-liner Script
    var := 29      ; <-- Not executed

scrolllock:: ; <-- Full Script
    Pause
    var := 29
    return   ; <-- Explicit return statement needed
```

If you have code on the first line, AHK will assume it is a quick one-liner and add in implicit return at the end. So `var := 29` after it won't be executed.

Comment: hi NonlinearFruit thanks for your answer, can an question have two answers?? please I currently have a question here http://superuser.com/questions/1149519/use-space-alt-q-to-trigger-some-actions-in-autohotkey hope you could check it out, thanks advanced.

Comment: @litu16 You can only accept one answer. Here are guidelines for [accepting](http://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer) and [up-voting](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/vote-up) answers.

Comment: ok thanks, this question was answered before, thanks anyway.