# Autohotkey - remap a solid key

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, autohotkey

is it possible for AHK to remap a key on the keyboard to another one? I mean not the character that they key prints, but the actual key, e.g. I have an international keyboard, it has an aditional key at the right side of the LeftShift, that prints `\` but the key above the Right Shift also prints `\`, I would like AHK to remap the left one, but not the right one.
So I can't do something like

```
\::Numpad0
```

cuz it would remap both keys, the one in the Left and in the Right, right

I know software like KeyTweak can do this, but it needs to restart all windows, and it applies to all programs, can AHK do this??

EDITED>>

Currently I'm doing this

```
SC056::Alt    ; SC056 is the key next to the LeftShift
```

I would like `SC056` to be Alt, so that it can work in conjuction with other key modifiers (Shift Ctrl Win) and in combination with any letter keys, ( A, E, I, O, U ), can AHK do this, or I necessarily have to use a key remapper?

I have tried to run my script and press   `SC056 & o' in order to send`Alt o` but it doesn't work.

THanks Advanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it should be possible.

Once an AutoHotkey script is running, open the running program from the tray icon.

`Tray Icon > Open`

`Menu > View > Key History`

This will show a history of keystrokes.

Press both keys of interest (as noted in the original post) and then refresh the Key History window.  The two keystrokes should show up as two different SC values which can then be used for two different hotkey definitions.

Comment: This is also the easiest way to determine a scan code for generally anything without referencing a master list... just hit the keys you want to test and then read out the SC value

Comment: yes thanks, I just got viewed on google, thanks again

Comment: could you please help me on this one, http://superuser.com/questions/1148186/autohotkey-set-a-hotkey-to-toggle-disabled-enabled-a-hole-autohotkey-script/1149073?noredirect=1#comment1652491_1149073 I have a problem with the answer, I posted my problem in a comment in the answer, thanks advanced.

Comment: Hi JJhonston, I did it, but it doesn't work with Alt, I reedited the question, please could you check it out? thanks Advanced.

Answer (score 1):

This is offtopic but you could remap those keys with [Sharpkeys](https://sharpkeys.codeplex.com/). It will let you change keys in registry.

Comment: so AHK can't remap keys, so that they can be userd with other modifier keys???

Comment: No, remap will only work while script is acive, and there could be a problem with some applications, games, etc. With Sharpkeys  you will remap key in registry. It will be permanent swap for whole Winsows OS, e.g. if you enter BIOS remap will not work. You can remap multiple keys to one, you can swap key and do all kind of crazy stuff. You will also need to log off after every remap.