# AutoHotKey - how to focus on a window again after running some actions

Tags: autohotkey, hotkeys

I use AHK 1.1 to set the capslock to be a hotkey to toogle ArtRage full screen mode (workbench mode), I do so, because ArtRage doesn't allow me to set CapsLock as a hotkey, but I'm quite used to use that key to do that in many programs, so I thought AHK could help me.

I tried this and it worked:

```
;   AR4 Toggle Workbench Mode
If WinActive("ahk_class ArtRage 3")

Capslock::
Sleep 20
Send {SC037 Down}   ;   NumpadMult
Sleep 10
Send {SC037 Up} ;   NumpadMult
Sleep 90
WinActivate, ahk_class ArtRage 3
return

#If
```

So the script works fine, but then somehow ArtRage window loses focus, I mean I still see the ArtRage window, but I noticed that it loses focus, because if I want to run another AHK hotkey (that runs only `#If WinActive("ahk_class ArtRage 3")` ) immediately after the script above is done, it will not detect ArtRage window as open, so it will not run, unless I manually click ArtRage window.

I tried to focus again after the `Capslock` (toggle Workbench Mode) is done, but `WinActivate, ahk_class ArtRage 3` doesn't refocus on ArtRage window, isn't there another way to refocus on a window in AHK?

EDITED >>>
how can I place a `IfWinExist("ahk_class ArtRage 3")` at the end of a piece of actions? cuz I can't just run it on top of my AHK script cuz it would always focus on ArtRage, even if I'm working in other apps right?, I tried this but it is not in a proper syntax, could you please post an example??

```
#If WinActive("ahk_class ArtRage 3")

Capslock::
Send {SC037 Down}   ;   NumpadMult
Sleep 30
Send {SC037 Up} ;   NumpadMult
Sleep 30
IfWinExist("ahk_class ArtRage 3")
    WinActivate, ahk_class ArtRage 3
return

#If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (first of all as standalone script):

```
;   AR4 Toggle Workbench Mode
#If WinActive("ahk_class ArtRage 3")

    Capslock::
    KeyWait, Capslock   ;  wait until Capslock is released 
    Sleep 20
    Send {NumpadMult}
    Sleep 90
    If !WinActive("ahk_class ArtRage 3")  ;  means: IfWinNotActive
    {
        Loop
        {           
            ;  Which window becomes active in this case?
            WinGetTitle, ActiveTitle, A
            WinGetClass, ActiveClass, A
            ToolTip, Active Window:`n%ActiveTitle%  ahk_class %ActiveClass%
            WinActivate, ahk_class ArtRage 3
            Sleep 50
            If WinActive("ahk_class ArtRage 3")
            {
                ToolTip
                break
            }                   
        }
    }
    return

#If

Esc:: ExitApp
```

Comment: Thanks user 3419297 I tried it, and I realized that when the workbench Mode is enabled, somehow ArtRage (`ahk_class ArtRage 3`) becomes (`ahk_class ToolWindow`). So I just replace `#If WinActive("ahk_class ArtRage 3")` with `#If WinActive("ahk_class ArtRage 3") or WinActive("ahk_class ToolWindow")` in all my ArtRage actions, what do you think about doing so? btw that AHK ToolTip rocks cuz even the "Window Spy" couldn't detect that window, why didn't you mention it earlier, thanks again.

Comment: #If ("WinActive("ahk_class ArtRage 3") or WinActive("ahk_class ToolWindow")) is OK. Try it out.

Comment: Hi, user 3419297, I have been stuck with a problem regarded to mouse coordinates, cuz when toogling the workbench mode (full screen) the coordinates of the mousemove get crazy (they are not accurate), so I would like to use always coordinates relative to screen, please could you help me out, thanks advanced. http://superuser.com/questions/1151560/autohotkey-coordinates-of-mouse-movement-a-little-off