# autohotkey - Coordinates of mouse movement a little off

Tags: mouse, autohotkey

when switching between full screen mode on an app, the coordinates of the `MouseClick, Click, MouseMove` are little off (not accurate) I have tried also `ControlClick` but I just cant get it working, it clicks, but it doesn't move the cursor. So I would like to set the coordinates to be always relative to screen.
How can I do that?

I read something about `CoordMode, Mouse, Screen`

but I don't know exactly how or where to put it in my ahk script, I have tried...

```
#Persistent
#InstallMouseHook


CoordMode, Mouse, Screen
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
```

How should I do it? and then how should I use the `mousemove` after that?

thanks advanced.

Comment: Try to find out: 1) What info shows Window Spy when this window is active (Window Title and Class, Active Window Position) in both cases (normal mode and full screen mode)? 2) What are the coordinates of the position you want click at in both cases? 3) Are those coordinates directly related or proportional to each other? 4) Is there a control (ClassNN) at the specified coordinates?

Comment: Hi user341929, is the ArtRage case, so the windows are the `ahk_class ArtRage 3` and `ahk_class ToolWindow` the coordinates are the same (x y values) but somehow in the `ahk_class ToolWindow` they are off, ArtRage always have those 2 windows, I solved puting `CoordMode, Mouse, Screen` at the top of my script, and using the `MouseClick, Left, ParamA, ParamB` so it works well inside functions also. No it didn't show any NN class that I can remember. Please could you help me wthis http://superuser.com/questions/1151766/autohotkey-problems-when-using-if-else-if-statements-inside-functions thanksAd